# std::atomic_is_lock_free() returns false for shared_ptr. Are there any other options for lockfree concurrent shared_ptr operations?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, shared-ptr, atomic

I have a shared_ptr that will be accessed by multiple threads.  I'm using the std::atomic [functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) for shared_ptr to make this thread safe.  std::atomic_is_lock_free() checks to see if std::atomic is truly using CPU atomic operations rather than locks.

the notes for this function say:

> All atomic types except for std::atomic_flag may be implemented using mutexes or other locking operations, rather than using the lock-free atomic CPU instructions. **Atomic types are also allowed to be sometimes lock-free, e.g. if only aligned memory accesses are naturally atomic on a given architecture, misaligned objects of the same type have to use locks.** If the type is sometimes lock-free, then the function (1) or its member function equivalent has to be used to determine if the particular instance is lock-free.

Running this bit of code returns false both on MacOS Mavericks (w/ c++11 std) and Linux CentOS 5.6 (w/ boost).  I thought x86_64 had pretty robust atomic operations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> StringMap;

int main()
{

    std::shared_ptr<StringMap> pMap;
    std::atomic_store(&pMap, std::make_shared<StringMap>());
    std::cout << "unordered_map ptr is lock free:" << std::boolalpha << std::atomic_is_lock_free(&pMap) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

My question:  Am I out of luck as far as having these pointer operations be lock-free, or is there some alternative?

**edit**   This returns true:

```
std::atomic<StringMap*> apMap;
std::cout << "atomic ptr is lock free:" << std::boolalpha << apMap.is_lock_free() << "\n";
```

Comment: Uh... this doesn't compile.

Comment: I don't think there's any "normal" hardware on which you could implement a shared pointer which could be copied or assigned-to in a lockfree fashion. Maybe transactional memory would allow it.

Comment: That said, the free functions `atomic_load`/`atomic_store` appear to be fairly inefficient; at least that's what Herb Sutter is claiming in [his recent proposal](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/n4058).

Comment: @Brian - compiles just fine.  And I'm not using std:atomic<T>.  There are special std::atomic_xxx functions for shared_ptr.

Comment: Take a look at the discussion of rationale in [N2674](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2674.htm#rationale). Lock-free implementation is a research issue, but they note that [for some workloads there is performance improvement over mutexes & read-write locks despite the use of spinlocks in the baseline implementation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2674.htm#performance).

Comment: Lock-free code does not guarantee better performance and in a lot of circumstances it could actually mean significantly lower performance than lock-based alternatives. So, it's not necessarily a bad thing that shared_ptr is not lock-free. It does mean, however, that instead of using std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>, you'd be better off using explicit locks.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your use case, but your level of granularity for using atomics seems wrong. Lock-free writes rely on retrys (CAS): if original hasn't changed, update it, else redo operation based on the new value. This comparison is memcmp-like, so having an atomic shared_ptr will protect the ptr itself, not the data structure accessed through it.

Comment: [Continuing previous comment, as it's too long] So, if you want a lock-free map, you have to write a lock-free map or get an existing implementation of one. C++ Standard containers are not concurrency safe, not only due to implementation, their actual interfaces are not concurrency safe, so locks are needed.